# How to generate an id or a tag for a fragment in a Android class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know the method of generate the id of a fragment in a xml,but how to do it in a java class?
As it likes `public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{}` .And I want to use them by  findFragmentByTag or findFragmentById later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Create a constant in class MenuFragment        
    public final static String TAG = "MenuFragmentTag";
```

Which can be later used to create the fragment using findFragmentByTag:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MenuFragment.TAG);
```

Comment: Thank you.But if there is many fragments,the code will be ugly.So is there any better way to solve the problem?

Comment: hey, thats the only way I know when fragments are not defined in XML.